# Estimate a squared sum of the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $5\times 5$ Hermitian matrix:
    $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_1\\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & a_2\\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & a_3\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & a_4\\
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & 5
 \end{pmatrix},\ \ a_i\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Let $\lambda_1\leq \lambda_2\leq \lambda_3\leq \lambda_4\leq\lambda_5$ be the eigenvalues of $A$.
Show that 
    $$(\lambda_1-1)^2+(\lambda_2-2)^2+(\lambda_3-3)^2+(\lambda_4-4)^2+(\lambda_5-5)^2\leq 2(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2).$$

This is an question from my homework of matrix theory, I have no idea  how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $B = A - C$ where
$$
C = \operatorname{diag}[1,2,3,4,5] =
\pmatrix{1\\&2\\&&3\\&&&4\\&&&&5}
$$
From there, theorem III.2.8 from Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* is sufficient.

Comment: I don't understand why we have $\lambda_i(B)\geq \lambda_i(A)-\lambda_i(C)$.

Comment: You should have a statement in your textbook/notes which allows you to state that $\lambda_i(B + C) \leq \lambda_i(B) + \lambda_i(C)$.  Did you recently cover the max-min theorem?

Comment: But we have $\mathrm{tr}(B+C)=\mathrm{tr}(B)+\mathrm{tr}(C)$ which implies that $$\sum_i \lambda_i(B+C)=\sum_i \lambda_i(B)+\sum_i\lambda_i(C),$$ so if $\lambda_i(B+C)\leq \lambda_i(B)+\lambda_i(C)$, then we can infer that $\lambda_i(B+C)=\lambda_i(B)+\lambda_i(C)$.

Comment: I find something similar to the inequality [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/). We have $$ \lambda_{i+j-1}(A+B) \leq \lambda_i(A) + \lambda_j(B), \ \ \ \ \ (4)$$ whenever ${i,j \geq 1}$ and ${i+j-1 \leq n}$

Comment: I think that is what I really had in mind: Weyl's inequality

Comment: I hope the reference was useful to you.  In the end, it does come from Weyl's inequalities after all, but it's a bit more subtle than I had expected.

Comment: Yes, to prove the inequality, the theorem from the reference is sufficient. Thank you anyway.